# Where are my tray icons in the Unity 2D panel?

Tags: 11.10, indicator, unity-2d

I can not see any icons in the notification area. I am using Unity 2D in Ubuntu 11.10
.
Where are they?

Comment: I'm having the same issues since upgrading to 11.10. Applications that did not show up anymore as tray icons are e.g. Skype and JDownloader. But VLC has an correct Tray Icon showing

Answer (score 3):

To enable the Notification Area (Systray) for all applications, run the following command:

`gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['all']"`

You can only whitelist a certain application if you want, by using the following command:

`gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Mumble', 'Wine', 'Skype', 'hp-systray', 'YOUR_APPLICATION']"`

The above command includes the already whitelisted (by default) applications so you should replace `YOUR_APPLICATION` with the application you want to whitelist.

Comment: This does not work for Unity 2D on my 11.10. The only tray icon I see is Skype, but, say, DavMail or alltray are hidden. `$ gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist` returns `['all']`. I've rebooted after changing this setting as well.

Comment: Turns out this is a known bug in Unity 2D: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-2d/+bug/847525

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug that has been recently fixed https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-2d/+bug/847525 following the release of the fix the systray-whitelist change should work.

Comment: Thanks for the update, glad it finally got fixed. Now to try it...

Comment: Guess it just hasn't been pushed to the update repos yet...even though it's been 2 months. Using that daily ppa works though. Probably best to go ahead and use that repo since it seems unity-2d does have so many weird qwerks and bugs. Hoping it's not incredibly unstable, since that is usually what the -daily postfix means.

Answer (score 0):

The [daily PPA for U2D has the fix](https://launchpad.net/~unity-2d-team/+archive/unity-2d-daily).

I don't know if it's possible to get just the first update after the fix was applied.